# Putty SSH connection with different client IP-address

Tags: ssh, static-ip, putty

I am using `PuTTY` and a `VNC` viewer to control my Raspberry Pi.
Now, I have to change the static IP-address of the LAN Interface of my PC from:

```
192.168.0.1
```

to

```
ip: 192.168.1.20
netmask: 255.255.0.0
```

RPi IP:

```
ip: 192.168.10.100
netmask: 255.255.0.0
```

The problem is that `PuTTY` cannot connect to the Raspberry Pi anymore, if I do so.

Is it even possible to control the Raspberry Pi, if I change the client IP-address? And if so, what do I have to configure on the Raspberry Pi so that this works?

Here my properties of the LAN Interface on the PC (sorry, it's in german):

[image: PC lan properties]

Here my dhcpcd.conf on the RPi:

[image: RPi: dhcpcd.conf]

(I already tried to change `static routers` and `static domain_name_servers` to `192.168.1.20`)

And my interfaces:

> # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
>
> # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
>   # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
>
> # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
>   source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
>
> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> # WLAN-Interface Hostapd
>   allow-hotplug wlan0
>   iface wlan0 inet static
>   address 192.168.1.1
>   netmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: I think your problem is on network, you cannot access `192.168.0.XXX` IPs when you are on `192.168.**1**.XXX` IP, could you display your Raspberry IP and netmask?

Comment: Ah ok, yes of course:

Comment: IP address eth0: 192.168.10.100  Mask: 255.255.0.0

Comment: And the netmask on your PC? have you tried to ping the raspberry?

Comment: PC LAN-Connection 2:  IP-address: 192.168.1.20, Mask: 255.255.0.0

Comment: Ok, pinging the RPi does also not work.

Comment: If you try to ping from RPi to PC? could you do this?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try, in a second

Comment: Pinging 192.168.1.20 on the RPi does not work either.

Comment: The problem is obviously on network interface in your PC and/or RPi, write on question the complete configuration of both

Comment: If I change the IP on the PC back to 192.168.0.1, both side pinging and PuTTY work fine.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that would be dhcpcd.conf and Interfaces on the RPi and the LAN properties on windows

Comment: Did you bother to read the notes at the top of the file `# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'`? If so, why did you decide to ignore them?

Comment: I did everything according to tutorials. Do you say so, because of the WLAN-Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem.

The thing was, that my WLAN network already allocated the IP-addresses 192.168.1.X, so the RPi could not connect to the IP-address 192.168.1.20.

Now, I use 192.168.2.X for my WLAN network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

why you have setup `domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1`? maybe is better to use google DNS `8.8.8.8`

try to change netmask on `interfaces` and set it on `255.255.0.0`